# React slider not rendering correctly

Tags: reactjs

I want to use rc-slider for my project.
I want to display different pricing.
It should be like this:

[image: what it should look like]

but when i'm trying to implement the slider for my site, it looks like this:

[image: what it looks like]

And here's my code for the slider.

```
<div className="rc-slider rc-slider-with-marks">
                        <div className="rc-slider-rail" style={{backgroundColor: 'rgb(216, 216, 216)', height: 6}} />
                        <div className="rc-slider-track" style={{backgroundImage: 'linear-gradient(91deg, rgb(13, 119, 243), rgb(14, 126, 243))', height: 6, left: '0%', width: '0%'}} />
                        <div className="rc-slider-step"><span className="rc-slider-dot rc-slider-dot-active" style={{left: '0%', width: 10, height: 10, border: 'none', backgroundColor: 'rgb(27, 124, 239)', bottom: '-4px'}} /><span className="rc-slider-dot" style={{left: '14.2857%', width: 10, height: 10, border: 'none', backgroundColor: 'rgb(216, 216, 216)', bottom: '-4px'}} /><span className="rc-slider-dot" style={{left: '28.5714%', width: 10, height: 10, border: 'none', backgroundColor: 'rgb(216, 216, 216)', bottom: '-4px'}} /><span className="rc-slider-dot" style={{left: '42.8571%', width: 10, height: 10, border: 'none', backgroundColor: 'rgb(216, 216, 216)', bottom: '-4px'}} /><span className="rc-slider-dot" style={{left: '57.1429%', width: 10, height: 10, border: 'none', backgroundColor: 'rgb(216, 216, 216)', bottom: '-4px'}} /><span className="rc-slider-dot" style={{left: '71.4286%', width: 10, height: 10, border: 'none', backgroundColor: 'rgb(216, 216, 216)', bottom: '-4px'}} /><span className="rc-slider-dot" style={{left: '85.7143%', width: 10, height: 10, border: 'none', backgroundColor: 'rgb(216, 216, 216)', bottom: '-4px'}} /><span className="rc-slider-dot" style={{left: '100%', width: 10, height: 10, border: 'none', backgroundColor: 'rgb(216, 216, 216)', bottom: '-4px'}} /></div>
                        <div role="slider" tabIndex={0} aria-valuemin={10} aria-valuemax={80} aria-valuenow={10} aria-disabled="false" className="rc-slider-handle" style={{borderColor: 'rgb(27, 124, 239)', borderWidth: 7, marginTop: '-6px', height: 18, width: 18, backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 255, 255)', left: '0%'}} />
                        <div className="rc-slider-mark"><span className="rc-slider-mark-text rc-slider-mark-text-active" style={{width: '12.8571%', marginLeft: '-6.42857%', left: '0%'}}>25K</span><span className="rc-slider-mark-text" style={{width: '12.8571%', marginLeft: '-6.42857%', left: '14.2857%'}}>50K</span><span className="rc-slider-mark-text" style={{width: '12.8571%', marginLeft: '-6.42857%', left: '28.5714%'}}>100K</span><span className="rc-slider-mark-text" style={{width: '12.8571%', marginLeft: '-6.42857%', left: '42.8571%'}}>250K</span><span className="rc-slider-mark-text" style={{width: '12.8571%', marginLeft: '-6.42857%', left: '57.1429%'}}>500K</span><span className="rc-slider-mark-text" style={{width: '12.8571%', marginLeft: '-6.42857%', left: '71.4286%'}}>1M</span><span className="rc-slider-mark-text" style={{width: '12.8571%', marginLeft: '-6.42857%', left: '85.7143%'}}>3M</span><span className="rc-slider-mark-text" style={{width: '12.8571%', marginLeft: '-6.42857%', left: '100%'}}>5M</span></div>
                      </div>
```

And here's my css for the slider.

```
.view-container .upper-info .pricing-content-wrap .rc-slider {
  margin-bottom: 45px;
}
.view-container
  .upper-info
  .pricing-content-wrap
  .rc-slider
  .rc-slider-mark-text {
  bottom: -47px;
  color: #a4a4a4;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like you forgot to [import `rc-slider` CSS](https://github.com/react-component/slider/#usage).

```
import 'rc-slider/assets/index.css'
```

I tried to reproduce your issue [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/qz5p1v072q) and removing this CSS import leads to your broken behavior.
Otherwise, it's OK.

---

Also, note that using inline styles `stye={{ prop: value, etc... }}`is not a good practice, consider moving them to CSS and operate with class names only in JSX.

Another thing to improve is boilerplate markup. You can use `map`s to reduce the amount of code:

```
const marks = ['50K', '100K', '250K']

// in render
<div className="slider-rail">
  {marks.map(m => <SliderDot key={m} />)}
</div>
<div className="slider-handle">
  {marks.map(m => <SliderMark key={m} label={m} />)}
</div>

// SliderDot
const SliderDot = () =>
  <span
    className="rc-slider-dot"
    style={{
     left: '85.7143%',
     width: 10,
     height: 10,
     border: 'none',
     backgroundColor: 'rgb(216, 216, 216)',
     bottom: '-4px',
    }}
  />

// SliderMark
const SliderMark = ({ label }) =>
  <span
    className="rc-slider-mark-text"
    style={{width: '12.8571%', marginLeft: '-6.42857%', left: '100%'}}
  >
    {label}
  </span>
```

Comment: added few notes to improve

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar issue on my Rails app: the whole slider didn't show up even with the `import 'rc-slider/assets/index.css'` line within the component.

I've just removed it and called it in my main scss file. Now, it works like a charm, hope it helps some people!